# How to use addcontentsline{}{}{} inside the index?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, overleaf, makeindex, addlines

I want to add the abstract with its original Roman number. I have the Abstract in the IV page, something like this: \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}. `
[image: Abstract][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn0pS.jpg)
[image: Index][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsmaM.jpg)

But in the index the Abstract appears with the VI number and this is not correct.
Please, help me. I want to add the Special thanks, Abstract and then the full table of contents (chapters, sections, etc.).

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[rflt]{floatflt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined] {algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{shorttoc,regexpatch}
\spanishdecimal{.}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\author{Ing. NAME}
\title{T}
\include{Acronimos}
\pagestyle{plain}


\begin{document}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
    \frontmatter
%                            PORTADA
        \include{portada/Portada}
%                            AGRADECIMIENTOS
        \include{Agradecimientos/Agradecimientos}
%                              RESUMEN
        \include{Resumen/Resumen}
%                        INDICE GRAL. Y TABLAS
        \include{Resumen/Abstract}
%                           Abstract
         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
         \tableofcontents
         \listoftables
         
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
    \mainmatter
%                           CAPITULO 1 INTRODUCCIÓN
        \include{Capítulo1/Capitulo1}
%                      CAPITULO 2 Estudio de la turbina eólica
        \include{Capítulo2/Turbina_eólica}
%     CAPITULO 3 Métodos de agregación de un parque eólico
        \include{Capítulo3/Capitulo3}
%     CAPITULO 4 Programación de método agregado en Python
        \include{Capítulo4/Capitulo4}
%     CAPITULO 5 Resultados
        \include{Capítulo5/Capítulo5}
%     CAPITULO 6 Conclusiones
        \include{Capítulo6/Capítulo6}
%------------------------------------------------------------------
    \backmatter
%                           BIBLIOGRAFÍA
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{Bibliografía/Bibliografía.bib}
%------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: move `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}`  to the start of  `Resumen/Abstract.tex`

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}` to the start of `Resumen/Abstract.tex` so it is written on the first page of the abstract, not after the last page of it.